# How to tell if app is running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode?

Tags: c#-2.0, 32bit-64bit

I have a C# project with target platform set to "Any CPU".
As I understand, the app will be compiled from MSIL to 32-bit on regular
Windows (x86) and 64-bit for 64-bit Windows. Is it possible to show
at runtime what mode it is running in ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Directive to indicate 32-bit or 64-bit build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076414/c-directive-to-indicate-32-bit-or-64-bit-build)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are some of the ways :
http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-how-to-determine-processor-64-bit-or-32-bit/

Comment: Actually the IsWow64Process API method seems to be just what I need.
Thanks!