# Cs file acting weird in vs

Tags: c#, if-statement, uwp

```
#if _WIN32
        const string DLL_NAME = "uFCoder-x86.dll"; // for x86 target
#elif _WIN64
        const string DLL_NAME = "uFCoder-x86_64.dll"; // for x64 target
#else // #elif _ARM
        const string DLL_NAME = "uFCoder-arm.dll"; // for ARM target
#endif
```

Does anyone know what's happening right here? I tried calling my cs file from MainPage and run in debug 64/84. By right, it should change accordingly when i toggle between running in 64/84 but after moving the file to a new location it stuck at else condition all the way and the return went wrong as well. Im running this in UWP Visual studio.

Comment: Are you sure, that `_WIN32` or `_WIN64` macros are defined?

Comment: I believe `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` not to be default defines in .Net projects. You would have to add them to your project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313402/preprocessor-directive-in-c-sharp-for-importing-based-on-platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preprocessor directive in C# for importing based on platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313402/preprocessor-directive-in-c-sharp-for-importing-based-on-platform)

Comment: In the future consider giving your questions a meaningful title. This way you might find your answer in the "related" questions.

Comment: Noted, but i've already indicated in there. It seems like i'm unable to get the value return.

Answer (score 0):

There are no _WIN32 or _WIN64 preprocessor directives in C# out of the box. Please see [#if (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

You will have to define them yourself or use another mechanism. You could check out [C# Directive to indicate 32-bit or 64-bit build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076414/c-sharp-directive-to-indicate-32-bit-or-64-bit-build)

---

## To define the symbols yourself

Solution properties -> Project properties -> Build -> Add them to *Conditional compilation symbols:*

[image]

Remember to add them to debug and release configurations.

Also, please note that this is per project, not for the whole solution.